# what is $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+2\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}dt$?

Tags: integration

The question is : Is $\sqrt 3$ the length of $$\Gamma =\{\gamma (t)=(t,\sin(t),\sqrt 2\cos(t))\mid t\in [0,1]\} \ \ ?$$
So it is $$\int_0^1\|\gamma '(t)\|dt=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+2\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}dt$$

I tries to do many substitution as $\cos^2(t)=\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}$, $\sin^2(t)=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}$, or $1=\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)$ but I can't conclude. I'm sure there is a trick but I don't see it, could someone help ?

Comment: Your integral leads to an Elliptic one: $$\sqrt {3}{\it EllipticE} \left( 1/3\,\sqrt {3} \right) -\sqrt {3}{\it 
EllipticE} \left( \cos \left( 1 \right) ,1/3\,\sqrt {3} \right) 
$$

Comment: This question was ask to a second year of bachelor, so is there an other way to answer ?

Comment: I don't know, i have only cosidered your integral

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misreading the question that was posed to you. It asks if $\sqrt{3}$ can be the value of said integral. It is possible to avoid straight-forward integration by exploring the possibility that it may not. To this end you may be able to find an (easy) inequality to show this.

Notice that $2+\sin^2(t) < 3$ for every $t\in[0;1]$. Thus:
$$||\Gamma||=\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{2+\sin^2(t)} \mathrm{d}t < \int\limits_0^1\sqrt{3} \mathrm{d}t=\sqrt{3},$$ which answers your question.

Comment: Very nice ! Good job :)

Comment: Nice and simple and +1 ! Looking at some comments, other people did misread the question.

Answer (score 3):

$$1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$$
$$2=1+\cos^2x+\sin^2x$$
$$2+\sin^2x=1+\cos^2x+2\sin^2x$$
so
$$||\Gamma||=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\cos^2x+2\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{2+\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx$$
Then recall the definition of the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind
$$\mathrm E(\phi,k)=\int_0^\phi\sqrt{1-k\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx$$
So we have that 
$$||\Gamma||=\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm E\bigg(1,-\frac12\bigg)\approx 1.064728654529...$$
Which might (but probably not) have a closed form